# building a package from source whose binary is already installed

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, build, fedora

I need to build a python module from source. It is just my second build and I'm a bit confused regarding the interaction between built packages and binaries installed through package manager.

Do I need to uninstall the binary first?

If I don't need to Will it overwrite the installed version or will both be available?

If it will not overwrite how can I import the built version into python?

Thank you all!

p.s: If it is case sensitive I'm on fedora 24 and the package is matplotlib which is installed through a setup.py.

Comment: I did the safe thing and removed the binaries before build.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use `virtualenv` and build your package inside. Is it really necessary to install via `setup.py`? If not, you can consider using `pip` to install your package inside `virtualenv`.

Comment: you can also install packages by `python setup.py install` into a virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I did the safe thing and removed the binaries before build.
building a scientific virtualenv seems like a good idea.